# onClick JavaScript doesn't work at the first access (page access)

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I have created a JavaScript function that doesn't work when we first access the web page. It will only work either by refreshing the page or accessing it for the second time.

How do I make sure that it works even when we access the page for the first time?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            
    /*--adding/subtracting no. of seats and price-- */

    function calculateSeat()
    {      
        var nums = [document.getElementById('number_seat0').value, document.getElementById('number_seat1').value,document.getElementById('number_seat2').value,document.getElementById('number_seat3').value,document.getElementById('number_seat4').value];
                
        var num = 0;
                
        for (i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            num += +nums[i];
        }
                          
        document.getElementById('total_seat').value = num;
        document.getElementById('total_amount').value = parseFloat(num * <?php echo $_SESSION['price'] ;?>).toFixed(2);
      };
</script>
```

Comment: How are you calling `calculateSeat`?

Comment: `num += +nums[i];` Waat?

Comment: Have you tried an IIFE?  Or `window.onload`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly This is a shortcut to `Number()`.

Comment: @user1238298857653768728 We need more to help :-)

Comment: I have tried calling calculateSeat and no problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Check below sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateSeat() {

        // your php variables
        var phpPrice = parseInt('<?php echo $_SESSION['price'] ;?>');

        // shortcut
        var $byId = document.getElementById; //faster that querySelector

        // list of your DOM elements with ids
        var ids = ['number_seat0', 'number_seat1', 'number_seat2', 'number_seat3', 'number_seat4'];

        // function that will be used in [].reduce
        // to calculate your result
        function getSum(total, id) {
            return total + ( +$byId( id ).value );
        };

        // total number
        // Array.reduce docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
        var result = ids.reduce(getSum);

        $byId('total_seat').value = result;
        $byId('total_amount').value = (result * phpPrice).toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually managed to resolve this issue by simply placing the script at the bottom of the body tag instead of the head (note: where it was previously).